# Removing null values from Python csv import

Tags: python, csv, tkinter

I have this program I've been working on. I have two questions. First, **how do I remove null values from my arrays after or before I import them?** Second, **Is there a better way to write this**. I know I can do some more object-oriented programming with it but quite frankly I really confuse me right now.

```
######imports python tools need for ui and csv reading 
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import csv

#####establishes arrays that the lables and scripst are saved in 
smename = []
smescript = []
rname = []
rscript = []
acname = []
acscript = []
tsname = []
tsscript = []

#####pulls infor from csv and imports to arrays
for d in csv.DictReader(open('script.csv')):
     smename.append((d['smename']))
     smescript.append((d['smescript']))
     rname.append((d['rname']))
     rscript.append((d['rscript']))
     acname.append((d['acname']))
     acscript.append((d['acscript']))
     tsname.append((d['tsname']))
     tsscript.append((d['tsscript']))

#####functions for all the option boxes to pull the needed scripts based on the button lable
def index(*entry):
     dex = smename.index(*entry)
     r = Tk()
     r.withdraw()
     r.clipboard_clear()
     r.clipboard_append(smescript[dex])
     r.update() 
     r.destroy()
     tkvar1.set('Start, Middle, & End')

def rindex(*entry):
     dex = rname.index(*entry)
     r = Tk()
     r.withdraw()
     r.clipboard_clear()
     r.clipboard_append(rscript[dex])
     r.update() 
     r.destroy()
     tkvar2.set('Remote')

def acindex(*entry):
     dex = acname.index(*entry)
     r = Tk()
     r.withdraw()
     r.clipboard_clear()
     r.clipboard_append(acscript[dex])
     r.update() 
     r.destroy()
     tkvar3.set('Abandoned Chat?')

def tsindex(*entry):
     dex = tsname.index(*entry)
     r = Tk()
     r.withdraw()
     r.clipboard_clear()
     r.clpboard_append(tsscript[dex])
     r.update() 
     r.destroy()
     tkvar4.set('Troubleshooting Steps')

#####establishes ui infromation and features    
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('HD Tools')
root.attributes("-topmost", True)
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack(pady = 5, padx = 5)

####simple option box
tkvar1 = StringVar(root)
popupMenu = OptionMenu(frame, tkvar1, *smename, command=index)
popupMenu.configure(width=20)
popupMenu.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
tkvar1.set('Start, Middle, & End')

tkvar2 = StringVar(root)
popupMenu = OptionMenu(frame, tkvar2, *rname, command=rindex)
popupMenu.configure(width=20)
popupMenu.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
tkvar2.set('Remote')

tkvar3 = StringVar(root)
popupMenu = OptionMenu(frame, tkvar3, *acname, command=acindex)
popupMenu.configure(width=20)
popupMenu.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
tkvar3.set('Abandoned Chat?')

tkvar4 = StringVar(root)
popupMenu = OptionMenu(frame, tkvar4, *tsname, command=tsindex)
popupMenu.configure(width=20)
popupMenu.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
tkvar4.set('Troubleshooting Steps')

#####runs the mainloop to start the ui =
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove `None` and false-y values from a `list` using `filter`:

```
>>> rg = [ 'hello', None, None, 'stack', '' ]
>>> rg = list(filter(None, rg))
>>> rg
[ 'hello', 'stack' ]
```

---

The easiest thing to do, even without using object-oriented programming, is keeping your code DRY.  This means, if you see yourself using the same parts of code over and over, try and make the code that gets reused into a separate function.  For example,

```
####simple option box
tkvar1 = StringVar(root)
popupMenu = OptionMenu(frame, tkvar1, *smename, command=index)
popupMenu.configure(width=20)
popupMenu.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
tkvar1.set('Start, Middle, & End')

tkvar2 = StringVar(root)
popupMenu = OptionMenu(frame, tkvar2, *rname, command=rindex)
popupMenu.configure(width=20)
popupMenu.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
tkvar2.set('Remote')
```

These two blocks are largely the same except for a few small differences.  You can combine those into one reusable function:

```
def add_grid(data, command, title, row):
    var = StringVar(root)
    popupMenu = OptionMenu(frame, var, *data, command=command)
    popupMenu.configure(width=20)
    popupMenu.grid(row = row, column = 1)
    var.set(title)

add_grid(smename, index, 'Start, Middle, & End', 1)
add_grid(rname, rindex, 'Remote', 2)
```

Comment: Your filter worked perfectly. I'm trying to simplify my script with your second suggestion but I keep getting an error about the tkvar2 I'm assuming that this is due to the variable, not change. I'm trying to fix this by just putting tkvar = ('tkvar'.format(row)) in front of it. but I continue to get AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'set'

Comment: You're right--there was an error in my original answer.  I've updated it for you.